# PHP error logging not comprehensive?

Tags: php, logging, interpreter

I'm working with PHP and have got the error logging turned on and turned up with:

> ```
> error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
>
> log_errors = On
> error_log = /path/to/file
> display_errors = Off
> ```

Now this log files catches most PHP errors but occasionally I will make a change and have the page fail to display with no logging to the file.

A specific example of this is if I do:

```
 interface InterfaceClass
 {
     public function someFunction();
 }

 class InterfaceInheriter implements InterfaceClass
 { 
     final public function someFunction()
     {

     }   
 }

  class FirstDerived extends InterfaceInheriter
  {   
      public function someFunction()
      {

      }
 }
```

Now this is all well and good, and i'm sure I have made some error, but where can I get the feedback from the interpreter for this?

ANSWER:
Since i'm using Wordpress it turns out that it was somehow filtering out some log messages. I fixed it in the end by setting the appropriate logging configuration for Wordpress.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Granted, I'm logging to Apache's error_log, but I get [Fri Jul 02 02:49:04 2010] [error] [client 93.108.152.52] PHP Fatal error:  Class InterfaceInheriter contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (InterfaceInheriter::someFunction) in /home/sites/main/a.php on line 10

Comment: Yep right you are, I didn't design that example particularly well. I have updated the question with one I just tested that fails and should yield no error logs.

Comment: I still get an error: [Fri Jul 02 03:51:40 2010] [error] [client 93.108.152.52] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot override final method InterfaceInheriter::someFunction() in /home/sites/main/a.php on line 16

Comment: that's interesting I definitely get nothing. I'll have another look at my config and do some general debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try placing error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); in the file..

Comment: It's already set in php.ini. Why would it need to be set again with a function?

Comment: if the file was included and another script higher up the execution chain was setting error_reporting with a function too.. - simple thing to try for an easy catch when debugging..

Comment: tried it and the errors get logged correctly. I'm using Wordpress so now I just have to work out what stupidity it is doing to selectively filter my error logs.